# Nagios 4.4.2 passive service resetting to OK

Tags: nagios

I have a passive service that is not working as I hoped/expected.  This is an async service.  It sends an NRDP passive message upon state change.  So if an alarm goes off then, it sends out a warning message, and when the alarm is corrected the state changes and sends out an OK message.  Upon an alarm, the responsible person is notified about a problem.

The problem is that after the freshness_threshold of 3 minutes, it is reset by nagios back to OK state and an OK notification is sent to the responsible person (as per the Notifications page).  I thought, per an article that I read, that it would turn to critical (but that maybe for active).

My service cache configuration is as follows:

```
define service {
        host_name       sensorshost
        service_description     sensor-116
        display_name    sensor-116
        check_period    24x7
        check_command   check_dummy!0
        contact_groups  sensor-116-contact-group
        notification_period     24x7
        initial_state   o
        importance      0
        check_interval  5.000000
        retry_interval  1.000000
        max_check_attempts      1
        is_volatile     0
        parallelize_check       1
        active_checks_enabled   0
        passive_checks_enabled  1
        obsess  1
        event_handler_enabled   1
        low_flap_threshold      0.000000
        high_flap_threshold     0.000000
        flap_detection_enabled  0
        flap_detection_options  a
        freshness_threshold     180
        check_freshness 1
        notification_options    r,w,u,c
        notifications_enabled   1
        notification_interval   60.000000
        first_notification_delay        0.000000
        stalking_options        n
        process_perf_data       1
        retain_status_information       1
        retain_nonstatus_information    1
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

A good place to start is always the [Nagios documentation](https://assets.nagios.com/downloads/nagioscore/docs/nagioscore/3/en/freshness.html):

> ### How Does Freshness Checking Work?
>
> Nagios periodically checks the freshness of the results for all hosts
>   services that have freshness checking enabled.
>
> - A freshness threshold is calculated for each host or service.
> - For each host/service, the age of its last check result is compared with the freshness threshold.
> - If the age of the last check result is greater than the freshness threshold, the check result is considered "stale".
> - If the check results is found to be stale, Nagios will force an active check of the host or service by executing the command specified
>     by in the host or service definition.
>
> **Tip:** An active check is executed even if active checks are disabled on a program-wide or host- or service-specific basis.

In your case, if the passive check result is older than `180` time-units (normally seconds, but this is configurable), then an "active check" (meaning your `check_command`) will be run to try and rectify the situation.

Nagios maps exit codes to service states, so if `check_dummy!0` exits with code `0` this would explain why the service goes back to OK.

Comment: Thanks for the precise explanation.  I have **active_checks_enabled 0**, I thought that it would not poll the service.  A service is required to have a **check_command**.  Is a better **check_command** available?

Comment: Re-read this part in the quoted documentation: "An active check is executed even if active checks are disabled on a program-wide or host- or service-specific basis." I am not sure what you mean by a "better" check command, I think you need to re-think what you're doing rather than the technicals of it. There's no point in having freshness checking if you don't have a command that will somehow rectify the fact that your check results are stale.

Comment: Thank you again.  I have removed the **freshness** configuration and it solved the automatically returning to OK.  I will continue to look for a replacement of check_dummy, or writing my own **check** script.

Comment: I have written my replacement for check_dummy, it can be found https://github.com/PHuhn/RaspberryPI/tree/master/Nagios/libexec  The script obtains the current last hard state and exits with that.  I am now able to get multiple notifications per the configured interval.

Comment: Glad to hear it, please mark this as the resolution if it resolved your problem.